# Dublin Preclearance for transit to third country

Tags: air-travel, airports, mexico, dublin

I am wondering if i can tap into the collective wisdom/knowledge of the hive mind. if anyone with knowledge or experience please share with me

I'm planning a trip from London Heathrow to Cancun, with a stopover in Dublin and then another one in DFW (Dallas/Fort Worth). I'm wondering if I can go through the Preclearance process in Dublin, even though I'm heading to Mexico. The reason I'm asking is because I've got a pretty tight connection time in DFW, only 75 minutes between flights. Using Preclearance in Dublin could really help me make that connection. Also, does anyone know if my checked bags will be automatically sent on to Cancun?

Comment: You don't have a choice about where you will clear US immigration and customs.  Every flight to the US is either entirely precleared or not at all.  You will clear in Dublin unless the preclearance facilities are closed for some reason.

Comment: @phoog Not actually true! Weirdly, and uselessly, the preclearance process is *voluntary*. If you're determined to have a bad day, you can opt out and directly board the plane. (You will be detained when it lands so they can do actual immigration processing on you.)

Comment: @Sneftel Reference?

Comment: @DJClayworth see the [CBP field manual](https://www.shusterman.com/pdf/cbpinspectorsfieldmanual.pdf), section 24.2.

Comment: @Sneftel That's not quite what (that version of) the field manual says. It says "_INS cannot refuse boarding to any passenger. Rather, persons who are determined to be inadmissible are advised of this determination and are given the option of not traveling or of being placed in exclusion proceedings or expedited removal proceedings, as appropriate, upon arrival in the United States._" I'm pretty sure the airline will refuse boarding...

Comment: @jcaron could be, I’m not sure anyone’s ever tried. As I mentioned, it’s not a useful thing to do.

Comment: @Sneftel: I imagine it is extremely useful for anyone who wants to request asylum. Or at least, it would be, if not for the fact that they're flying from Ireland, which is not especially known for violently oppressing its people (asylum seekers are generally supposed to seek asylum from the first safe country they enter).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all flights from Dublin landing in the US will go through preclearance in Dublin. In DFW you will not need to go through customs and (presuming the same PNR) will not need to re-check your bags.

Comment: How is this consonant with your assertion of voluntariness in your earlier comment?

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica I don't see what the relevance of my comment is to this answer.